# Why ReadOnly Property are globally changeable?

Tags: .net, vb.net, properties, private

I have a Data class for my hole application. This data class is access from many other classes in the application. I load the Data at the beginning and want that the Data is not changeable globally.

This is how it looks now (Example)

```
NotInheritable Class Data
Public NotInheritable Class Country
    Public CounCode As String = String.Empty
    Public ISOCode As String = String.Empty
    Public Name As String = String.Empty

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return CounCode + ": " + ISOCode + " - " + Name
    End Function
End Class

Private Shared m_Countries As List(Of Country) = Nothing
Public Shared ReadOnly Property Countries As List(Of Country)
    Get
        Return m_Countries
    End Get
End Property
Shared Sub New()
    m_Countries = New List(Of Country)
    Dim Country As Country = New Country
    Country.Name = "Germany"
    m_Countries.Add(Country)
    Country.Name = "Italy"
    m_Countries.Add(Country)
    Country.Name = "Spain"
    m_Countries.Add(Country)
End Sub
```

End Class

But when I do like this

```
    Dim countries As List(Of Data.Country) = Data.Countries
    countries(0).Name = "Hello World"

    Dim countries2 As List(Of Data.Country) = Data.Countries
    MessageBox.Show(countries(0).Name + " - " + countries2(0).Name)
```

I excpect "Hello World - Germany" but I'll get "Hello World - Hello World".
Why i can -globally- change the property? And how to solve this?
I want to allow the other classes to change the name of the country but not globally.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Marc said, there is no way to prevent this. You cannot assign a different collection to the property but the collection that property encapsulates can be changed (add/remove/change)

A work around is the following:

```
Imports System.Linq

Module StartupModule

    Sub Main()
        Dim users As New List(Of User) From {
            New User() With {.Name = "John"},
            New User() With {.Name = "Nick"}
        }

        Dim company As New Company(users)


        Console.WriteLine("names before change")
        For Each u In company.Users
            Console.WriteLine(u)
        Next
        Console.WriteLine()

        Console.WriteLine("change names")
        For Each u In company.Users
            u.Name = "something else"
        Next
        Console.WriteLine()

        Console.WriteLine("names after change")
        For Each u In company.Users
            Console.WriteLine(u)
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub


    Public Class Company
        Private _users As New List(Of User)    

        Public Sub New(users As List(Of User))
            Me.Users = users
        End Sub    

        Public Property Users As List(Of User)
            Get
                Return (From u In _users
                       Select DirectCast(u.Clone, User)).ToList
            End Get
            Private Set(value As List(Of User))
                _users = value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class


    Public Class User
        Implements ICloneable

        Public Property Name As String

        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return Name
        End Function

        Public Function Clone() As Object Implements ICloneable.Clone
            Return New User() With {.Name = Name}
        End Function
    End Class

End Module
```

The getter of the property always return a collection of clones of the original objects. So you have to implement the `ICloneable` to your class or just to create a function to return a clone of your object.

In that way, the changes are made in the clones collection, not changing the actual objects.

The catch in that approach is that whenever you refer to the collection (in the example the `Company.Users` collection), a new list is created wich is populated with the clones of the original items.

Comment: Thank You for your answer, I successfully try with cloning and this works but i thought there is an easier and better solution ...

Comment: @mts As Marc mentioned you could always use `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`

Answer (score 0):

It is the *collection property* that is read-only - not the collection itself, and not the items in the collection. You have not reassigned the collection to a new collection, which is the **only** thing that  a read-only field or property accessor prevents. It is functioning correctly.

Having a collection property readonly does **not** make the collection itself read-only (you can still add/remove/etc), and does **not** make the items in the collection read-only. For a read-only collection: try [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474(v=vs.110).aspx). For the items themselves: you'd have to make `Country.Name` read-only.

What you **cannot** do (outside of the constructor) is:

```
Data.Countries = New List(Of Country)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understand why I can change the property but what is the solution :)? When I make Country.Name read-only, other classes cant change the name for themself. I will try with ReadOnlyCollection. Thanks

Comment: @mts options there: 2 different types (one mutable, one immutable); popsicle immutability (a `Freeze()` method or similar)